# Rails concatenate sql columns and create one to many relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I've got two models: `Building` and `BuildingInfo`. I want to relate the two tables using two columns `townhall_level` and `name`.

Ideally it will work like the following: `Building.first.building_info` For instance `Building.first.townhall_level => 5` and `Building.first.name => cannon`, `Building.first.building_info` would access `BuildingInfo.where(townhall_level: 5, name:"cannon"`.

What's the best way to do this? Can I create a third column which concatenates `name` and `townhall_level`? Could I also use that column to create the belongs_to and has_many relationship?

Comment: `townhall_level` is a column defined in both: `Building` as well as in `BuildingInfo`?

Comment: Yes that is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple and straightforward:

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base

  def building_info
    BuildingInfo.find_by(townhall_level: townhall_level, name: name)
  end

end
```

It will be `nil` if nothing is found, and will return only the first record even if multiples are found. I also highly suggest that you add an index to the two columns through a migration:

```
add_index :building_infos, [:townhall_level, :name], name: 'building_infos_level_and_name'
```

Which will speed up searching, if you were concerned about performance.

Comment: Yeah, I was way over complicating it! Simplicity is my friend. How much faster is add_index? Why is it faster?

Comment: Aside from big queries dinamically built (like complex search engines or such), you should only search on database indexes. Speed: a LOT, I don't have numbers but we are talking about a HUGE difference. If you are using postgresql, you can have two indexes (one on townhall_level and one on name) instead of one over two (it's more flexible in this way, you'll get benefit for searching on the single columns too). Anyway imagine that with an index, postgresql keeps a sorted version of the table stored. So it's something like `log N` vs `N` complexity (might be more)

Answer (score 0):

mmm...I'm not sure this will work but you can do something like

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.bulding_info
    BuildingInfo.find_by(townhall_level: townhall_level, name: name)
  end
end
```

but I would really suggest you to put a `building_info_id` in the Building model and have a

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bulding_info
end
```